# If you click the check box in the html and click the button, you need to go to the next page, but it does not

Tags: html, checkbox, required

this question is my first question.
There are policies available in the site that I make, press the checkbox to accept it, eh button have to go to the next page, but I got the help I've run into even I do not know how it should be required but this is doesn't work

```
 <label for="myCheck">I agree:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" required>
  <a href="img.html" class="btn btn-outline-success" role="button">Let's go</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question well:

The user have to check the input in order to let him go to img.html. if that´s the case you can do this:

```
  <form action="img.html">

    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" required> I agree policies

    <button type="submit">Let's go</button>

  </form>
```